Use custom css along with PrimeNg themes
I have set up PrimeNG themes according to their official documentation. It works fine, but how can I write a few custom CSS styles with the themes?
I have this code in my mode-dark.css
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-dark-indigo/theme.css";

 app-root {
     background: black;
 }


This is injected through services. Dark and light theme CSS are applied, but the style of app-root is not.
Also this is obvious but app-root is not primeNg component.
I wrote this CSS in styles.css, and it worked there. Is this an issue of my style not being applied, or a file hierarchy issue? Is there a workaround for this?

please share minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated, also update the same on the question!
